# date piker does not close after opeing in react native

Tags: react-native, datetime

```
 const [mydate, setDate] = useState(new Date());
   const [displaymode, setMode] = useState('date');
   const [isDisplayDate, setShow] = useState(false);
   const changeSelectedDate = (event, selectedDate) => {
   const currentDate = selectedDate || mydate;
   setDate(currentDate);
};
const showMode = (currentMode) => {
   setShow(true);
   setMode(currentMode);
};
const displayDatepicker = () => {
   showMode('date');
};
return (
   <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View>
         <Button onPress={displayDatepicker} title="Show date picker!" />
            </View>
               {isDisplayDate && (
                  <DateTimePicker
                     testID="dateTimePicker"
                     value={mydate}
                     mode={displaymode}
                     is24Hour={true}
                     display="default"
                     onChange={changeSelectedDate}
            />
         )}
```

i have a button that opens a datepiker when i click ok on the date piker the date piker soes not close also i want the selected date to be console loged() when i click on ok

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add setShow(false) in function changeSelectedDate.
eg

```
const changeSelectedDate = (event, selectedDate) => {
   const currentDate = selectedDate || mydate;
   setDate(currentDate);
   setShow(false)
};
```

Comment: how to console.log() selected date

Comment: @adnan can u help me display the date that is selected

Comment: ok so now the datePicker closes? and now we want to see the selected date??

Comment: yes it closes can u help me with that disaplying of date

Comment: hey if you console.log(currentDate) in function  changeSelectedDate what does it display in console??
And you are not using it in the View part in render.

Comment: i am using moment js module to format the output of it
eg. moment(currentDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY')

Comment: i am prperty getting currentDate doesnot exist

Comment: i have edited my ans please send me output of it

Comment: i am getting only todays date not slected date

Comment: sorry for interrupting, @menucd if the date is now closing, just a reminder to choose the answer as the correct answer

Comment: @DeepanshParmani  Adanan i have created new quetion pls chek my profile i cannot tag u there